# Avoid hover effect on specific Child div though hover applied to Parent div

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with **hover**

I have 3 child div's like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">A</div>
    <div class="child2">B</div>
    <div class="child3">C</div>
</div>
```

I had applied hover on parant div to change color on child1 and child2 div.
Yet hover is applied over child3 div too....

Is there a way to **exclude** hover on child3 alone??

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
div.parent:hover {
    color: #909090;
}
```

In the the above example there has to be no change of color on font **"C"** though it is present inside parant div.

Comment: Do you want the color to only be applied to 1 and 2 even when hovering 3? or do you want only the child hovered to change color (except 3?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the style

```
.child3
{
    color : #000;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ADzhW/)**

Answer (score 6):

Just make your CSS more specific:

```
.parent:hover .child1, .parent:hover .child2 {
    color:#909090;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div.parent:hover {
    color:#909090;
}
```

Your CSS is saying "select DIV tags with class parent and apply the following CSS only on hover state, then change font color to #909090".

First, if you want hover state on the child, do this:

```
/* explanation: select DIV tags with "child" class on hover state */
div.parent div:hover {
    /* apply your CSS here */
}
```

If you want to make specific CSS for some tags and exclude it from other tags, be more specific. You can add more than 1 class to any tag. For example, let's add another class for child1 and child2 for special hover state, and exclude it for child3:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1 myHoverClass"></div>
    <div class="child2 myHoverClass"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Now it's easy to control that with CSS:

```
/* explanation: find parent class div, then select children DIV tags with class name "myHoverClass" and apply CSS for hover state only.. in this case, only child1 and child2 DIV tags */
div.parent div.myHoverClass:hover {
    /* apply your CSS here */
}
```

Note: watch out for spaces in CSS, they are very sensitive and it could completely mean something else without cautious use.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.parent:hover > :not(.child3) {
    color:#909090;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but note that is lumped in with other selectors too so *may* not be a true representation: "Advanced element selection using selectors like :nth-child(), :last-child, :first-of-type, etc."

Comment: Without a `>` child combinator, this would select all descendants except the `.child3` div itself, but including its children etc...

Comment: @robooneus Further note on browser compatibility: `:hover` is not supported on anything other than `<a>` elements in old versions of IE ;)

Comment: IE7 and up is fine with `:hover` on non-anchors, and IE6 is as good as dead, really ;)

Comment: Internet Explorer will get mad on this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.child1:hover, .child2:hover {
    color:#909090;
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yhD9A/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 div.parent:hover .child1,div.parent:hover .child2{
    color: #909090;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a different class to `child1` and `child2` like this may be:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="test child1"></div>
    <div class="test child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
</div>

.test:hover{background-color:red;}
```